# Passing BST to struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, binary-search-tree

I' would like to write a function that will pass all words and values from `BST` to struct array. In `tree` I have `words(node->word)` and `value(node->val)`.
In `main` I declare array of pair struct.

Here is my code:

```
void inOrder(Tree *node,pair *array[], int index)
{
    if(node == NULL){  // recursion anchor: when the node is null an empty leaf was reached (doesn't matter if it is left or right, just end the method call
       return;
    }
    inOrder(node->left, array, index);   // first do every left child tree
    array[index]->val= node->val;   // then write the data in the array
    array[index]->word = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(node->word)+1));
    strcpy(array[index]->word,node->word);
    index++;
    inOrder(node->right, array, index);  // do the same with the right child
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Tree *myTree = NULL;
    pair arr[5000];
    int index=0;
    ...
    inOrder(myTree,&arr,index);
    printf("%d",arr[0].val);
    zero(myTree);
    return 0;
}
```

Debugger says:

> Access violation writting location 0x0000001.

Comment: It will return Null always the way your code is setup correctly.

Comment: These limes do not execute ever.array[index]->val= node->val;   // then write the data in the array
    array[index]->word = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(node->word)+1));
    strcpy(array[index]->word,node->word);
    index++;
    inOrder(node->right, array, index);

Comment: @Maertin So what do you suggest? I Aint got any idea how to do this.

Comment: There are two issues here. One is error handling and the other is logic. Your line where you printF arR.value, you need to correct that to print only if arr[o].val not equal to null. Once you fix that, you won't get the error you mentioned. you also need to do the array value assignment in inOrder first before traversing to the child nodes. When you reach null after going through left child, you need to traverse back to parent node and then do right node. I don't really program in C++ - so unless I have the code in my machine in a suitable IDE, I don't know how I can help except with the logic

Comment: @Maertin Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see anything wrong with the code there. `inOrder` will return, then those two lines will run.

Comment: When it returns, it will exit function. Basically the first time a null is reached, the inOrder function is exited.

Comment: @Maertin But `inOrder` is called recursively. The outermost call won't hit null immediately, only the leaves.

Comment: Yes - it looks like that. I am typing from an iPad. So you can imagine my difficulty. Regardless, once it reaches the leftmost leaf,  what happens next?

Comment: @Maertin It returns, then the call outside of the leaf will go to the right (`inOrder(node->right, array, index);`).

Comment: You have another issue with `index`... You need to pass `index` as an `int *` instead of an `int` so that when recursive calls increase the index, the updated index is used in their callers and subsequent recursive calls.  Otherwise you'll frequently overwrite the same array locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is weird with the pointers here. Your `inOrder` function header expects an array of `pair` pointers, but you pass in a pointer to an array of `pair`s (which is actually just a chunk of random memory). I'm pretty sure that's where the pointer error comes from.

There are many ways to fix this, but I'll just put the one I like the best. Any reason why you're passing a pointer to a pointer instead of just the pointer? Try changing your function header:

```
void inOrder(Tree *node, pair *array, int index)
```

and access stuff like this:

```
array[index].val= node->val;   // then write the data in the array
array[index].word = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(node->word)+1));
strcpy(array[index].word,node->word);
```

and call it from `main` like this:

```
inOrder(myTree,arr,index);
```

I can't test it, unfortunately, but I think it should work.

P.S. Sorry for all the edits/deletions. I misread something.

Comment: Yeap, it does. Thanks for advice.